# single.php - how to mark current page in the loop

Tags: loop

I am using the following loop on `index.php`.
The current viewed page would be one of the link in the loop.
 **How to make sure it is marked as current?**

```
<ul id="questions" class="subpage">
      <?php 

          $index_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'faq', 'orderby' => 'modified', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
          while ( $index_query->have_posts() ) : $index_query->the_post();

        ?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_field('short_version'); ?> &raquo;</a></li>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
```

`get_field()` is a function from [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and has the following format:

`get_field($field_name, $post_id);`

Comment: What is `get_field()`? That's no default WP template tag.

Comment: @kaiser It's from [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a rewritten version of your code

```
<ul id="questions" class="subpage">
<?php 
$current_id = get_the_ID();

$index_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'faq', 'orderby' => 'modified', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
while ( $index_query->have_posts() ) : $index_query->the_post();
    if(get_the_ID() == $current_id)
        echo 'this post has the same ID as the current global one';
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_field('short_version'); ?> &raquo;</a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Please note that on the index.php you can have queries of single post types as well as of archives(depending on your theme). If in case of an archive this will match the first post of that archive only. If you want to match for other types of templates, please see the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: very strange, but does not work. when I do `echo $current_id ` outside the loop. It is getting `25`, but actual ID is `37`. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it. This must be within standard loop.`<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

On a `single.php` page you should have a `$post` object, which is created by WordPress for those pages. `$post->ID` is the ID of the 'current' page. Compare that number against the IDs in your loop. If they match 'mark' you post.

Be aware: You may need to save `$post` to another variable to avoid clobbering it when you run your loop, or use `$posts[0]` instead of `$post`.

Comment: Is it `$posts[0] ` because current post always will be first in the array?

Comment: Sort of. The `$posts` array is set on most (all ?) WordPress pages. On index pages it contains all of the posts that will be on the page. On 'single' pages, it only contains one. [`the_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) defines `$post` as each post in `$posts` as you loop through. That is why I think your loop may clobber it.